# backbone environment installation [package.json file is missing]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js

I'm now install the environment of the Backbone.js library.

And follow certain steps and I'm facing a problem.

I download all files needed [jquery - backbone.js - underscore]

and the next step is [npm install] and I know that I must have a file called [package.json]

**The problem is:** What this file is? and Where can i download it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the file you are looking for ?

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/package.json

I Suggest you anyway will download the js file from http://backbonejs.org/ and refrence it inside your application.

Comment: I downloaded the backbone.js from http://backbonejs.org/ but I don't know where can I download package.js file

Comment: Why do you need the package.json file?

Comment: The problem is this is the first time to use backbone.js and node.js and the tutorial write this command in cmd **npm install** and and give me an error **npm ERR! install couldn't read attendances**

Comment: You need to npm install backbone, and it will automatically get it from the online repository